# Getting "Malformed multipart body" when trying to upload video to YouTube

Tags: c#, youtube-data-api

I have an application that uploads videos to YouTube on behalf of our customers. We manage thousands of channels and upload thousands of videos a day. This has been working for years. The code is written in C#, .Net 4.7 (it was actually using a slightly older version, but I had to update it in order to recompile and test). It uses the REST API (not the SDK).

For some reason, the code broke the evening of Friday, Oct 12th, 2018. All of our requests to upload return with a 400 status and "Malformed multipart body." as the body.

We have not changed the code in at least 6 months (though likely over a year). I am able to reproduce the error on my dev machine. I looked at the raw http request in Fiddler and I don't see anything wrong with it, though I'm having difficulty finding the plain REST documentation to confirm the content-disposition headers. I know the JSON and video are fine (I validated the JSON and verified I'm able to upload the video directly to YouTube). Also, all of the other API calls we make work just fine. It's just uploading that is a problem.

Here's a copy of the HTTP request from Fiddler...

```
POST https://www.googleapis.com/upload/youtube/v3/videos?part=snippet,status HTTP/1.1
Authorization: Bearer <token>
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary="590ce98e-6411-4e49-8dde-d7aa06cb067d"
Host: www.googleapis.com
Content-Length: 8305362
Expect: 100-continue

--590ce98e-6411-4e49-8dde-d7aa06cb067d
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Content-Disposition: form-data; name=json; filename=file.json; filename*=utf-8''file.json

{"snippet":{"title":"77 Wakefield Street, Bald Hills, QLD, 4036","description":"77 Wakefield Street\r\n\r\nContact Brian Brewder for more information.\nTourFactory Corporate Headquarters\n123-456-7890\n\r\n","categoryId":19,"tags":["Tag1","Tag2"]},"status":{"privacyStatus":"public","embeddable":true}}
--590ce98e-6411-4e49-8dde-d7aa06cb067d
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="files"; filename="video"
Content-Type: video/x-msvideo

<video>
```

It seems like something must have changed on the YouTube side of the API, but I checked the blog and don't see anything listed. Since Google uses StackOverflow for support, I'm hoping somebody can help me identify the problem.

Comment: We're having the same issue, broke for us on 12th as well. Code (Qt/C++, self written as there isn't an official c++ library for this, for some reason) has worked well for over 3 years. Can't find any news on this. Time to reverse engineer i guess :\

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, apparently what caused the issue (And still does) is that now the

```
Content-Type: multipart/mixed;
```

is no longer accepted. I managed to get an error message by changing some stuff around, and said to only send `video/*` or `application/octet-stream`. Unfortunately, while i still got OK from the server by doing so, resulted in a broken youtube video

[image: broken youtube video]

At this point i tried playing with headers but with no success. The file would be accepted by YouTube but wouldn't be displayed correctly. I suspect they changed - or dropped - the non-resumable uploads API. If they did, i can't find an announcement on that.

So, my "solution" - well, a workaround - was to reimplement my upload function using the Resumable Upload protocol.

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/using_resumable_upload_protocol

This works and didn't take too long. Just make sure to set both X-Upload-Content-Length and x-upload-content-type for BOTH requests (metadata first and payload after getting the upload put URL).

So you first POST the same metadata (snippet and status) and get the PUT url

```
QByteArray responseLocation = reply->rawHeader( "Location" );
```

and then create the PUT request using the same X-Upload-Content-Length and x-upload-content-type

```
newrequest.setRawHeader( "X-Upload-Content-Length", QByteArray::number( video->size() ) );
newrequest.setRawHeader( "x-upload-content-type", "video/*" );
```

That worked for me - I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks. I suspect you are right about them dropping support for the non-resumable endpoint. I ended up rewriting our code to use the SDK which uses the resumable endpoint and everything seems to be working again.

Comment: Happy to hear you fixed it as well! Cheers!

Comment: @Andrea Any Chance your youtube upload code is public? It seems that just about all qt clients just arent working anymore.

Comment: Hey Akiva, unfortunately no, sorry. I work for a company and our source is not public. But as you see from my answer the fix was pretty easy, it shouldn't take too long to fix. Are you using a library? if so i may able to point out a fix.